trying to create a table on emulator but keeps crashing
Trying to display a table in new activity. New activity worked correctly, but started crashing emulator when I made the table code, please help. There's no error code so I don't see the problem.
Attempting to grab the double array of grades in the main class, and display a table with the header Subjects and the columns the names of the students.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/table_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".launchTable">


</TableLayout>

package com.example.myapplication;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

public class launchTable extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] subjects= {"Science", "Math", "English"};
        String[] students= {"Sarah", "John", "Emily", "Dave"};
        double[][] grades= MainActivity.grades;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launch_table);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        TableLayout tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
        for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            for (int j = 0; j < grades[i].length; j++) {
                TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(grades[i][j]));
                row.addView(textView);
            }
            tableLayout.addView(row);
        }
    }
}


Please share more code in "MainActivity" and Manifest

Where is the crash log? Share it so people can understand what is going wrong.

I was able to fix it, the emulator didn't like the line TableLayout tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.table_layout)  so I changed the xml file to a linear layout and made a table inside that

I think you should [edit] your answer and post the XML file with your changes that solved your problem. I think then it would be clear to others with similar problems to undertsand how the XML file needs to be changed.
